Typescript annotation of Pinia state persisted with useLocalStorage()
In my pinia based store I have state with following properties:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { ref } from 'vue'

export const useLoginStore = defineStore('login', () => {
  // State
  const isAuthenticated = useLocalStorage('isAuthenticated',false)
  const user = ref<{ name: string; email: string } | null>(null)
  const accessToken = ref<string | null>(null);

  // Actions
  const login = (userData: { name: string; email: string }, token: string) => {
    user.value = userData
    isAuthenticated.value = true
    accessToken.value = token
  }

  const logout = () => {
    user.value = null
    isAuthenticated.value = false
    accessToken.value = null;
  }

  return {
    isAuthenticated,
    user,
    accessToken,
    login,
    logout,
  }
})

Based on the VueUse docs I modified the first value as follows, since it infers simple types, but can't figure out how to explicitly pass more complex type annotations:
...
// State
const isAuthenticated = useLocalStorage('isAuthenticated', false)
const user = ???
const accessToken = ???
...

EDIT: added whole Pinia store for clarity

Can you clarify how these two snippets are connected? Did you replace pinia store with custom state that uses useLocalStorage or use them together? . Please, provide the rest of the code to give better idea what happens. If you wanted to have persistent pinia state, it would be better to use pinia persist plugin

I've added the rest of the code. The second snippet is just the state part with first value modified to make use of useLocaleStorage method of VueUse.

I see, glad you sorted this out. Notice that the use of pinia-plugin-persistedstate will likely be more performant and cause less problems. I cannot predict the possible implications of this composable being used together with pinia store. Btw you may not need isAuthenticated separate state, it's usually something like computed(() => !!token.value))

So the answer was rather obvious, but I am fairly beginner when it comes to TypeScript type annotation syntax. Hopefully this will save someone some time:
  const isAuthenticated = useLocalStorage('isAuthenticated', false)
  const user = useLocalStorage<{ name: string; email: string } | null>('user', null)
  const accessToken = useLocalStorage<string | null>('accessToken',null)

